# How to restriction users to publishing in Power App

Tags: powerapps

I am working in microsoft 365 power apps. In organization anyone know the possible solution, how to restrict users from publishing power app application.

Actually It governance advice to revoke publishing rights from users only a single ID (which is created for only development purpose) can published the power apps applications.